# Tallying incorrect answers for Javascript game

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So I am trying to make a javascript game for my geography class but I have run into some trouble, I can ask the questions and tell you if you're wrong or not but I would like to be able to keep track of the wrongs answers. I want to keep track using `for` loops but I'm not good at them, some help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the basis of what every question looks like, it's just that && is where I need to add a single mark to the incorrect tally which I am sure I need to use `for` loops for.

```
var y = "You are correct!!!"
var n = "You are incorrect!!!"

alert("Chapter 1, Human Cultural Connections. 1-10")
//==================================================
var Q1 = prompt("Demographers identify three different stages of life. 
They are children, working adults, and older adults. What is the age 
range for children? 0-13, 0-15, 0-18")

if (Q1 === "0-13")
{
alert(y)
}
else
{
alert(n) //&& add 1 tally to incorrect list
}
```

If someone could help me out with this it would be sooo helpful, and don't worry this is past do anyways but I still want to know how to do it for future projects!

p.s. I already have the script HTML so I don't need help with that.

Comment: [**This**](http://www.javascriptsource.com/miscellaneous/basic-javascript-quiz.html) might be of help.

Comment: How about `var correctCount = 0;` at the top and `correctCount++;` after the `alert(y)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable to keep track of incorrect answers:

```
var y = "You are correct!!!"
var n = "You are incorrect!!!"
var incorrectCount = 0;

alert("Chapter 1, Human Cultural Connections. 1-10")
//==================================================
var Q1 = prompt("Demographers identify three different stages of life. 
They are children, working adults, and older adults. What is the age 
range for children? 0-13, 0-15, 0-18")

if (Q1 === "0-13")
{
alert(y)
}
else
{
alert(n) //&& add 1 tally to incorrect list
incorrectCount++;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it, see what happens

Comment: It works perfectly, no all I need to do is figure out how to terminate the game when the counter hits 5

Answer (score 2):

```
var correct = [], // well store the index of the correctly answered questions here
    wrong = [], // well store the index of the incorrectly answered questions here
    questions = [
    {
        "question": "Demographers identify three different stages of life. They are children, working adults, and older adults. What is the age range for children?",
        "answers": ["0-13", "0-15", "0-18"],
        "correct": 0 // correct answer is item of index 0 in property "answers" (0-13)
    },
    {
        "question": "whats your favorite color?",
        "answers": ["red", "yellow", "blue", "purple"],
        "correct": 2 // blue
    }
];

for (var i in questions){
    var answer = prompt(questions[i].question + questions[i].answers.join(','));
    if (answer == questions[i].answers[questions[i].correct]){
        correct.push(i);
    }else{
        wrong.push(i);
    }    
}

alert('wrong number of answers: ' + wrong.length);
alert('correct number of answers: ' + correct.length);
alert('first wrong question: ' + questions[wrong[0]].question);
```

I know this is practically overwngineering what you asked for but it might give you better flexibility and knowledge as to how js for loops work. Hope it helps.